# Sharing code across two separate apps in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am currently developing two iOS applications: one for employees and one for managers.

I am using a different target for each app so that I can re-use code (like the model for a user, as employees & managers are all considered a user and only have different permission levels).

The two applications were started fairly recently, so I am considering re-writing them from scratch to use React Native (because I will be doing the exact apps for Android when the iOS apps are finished).

**My question is**: How easy is it to share code across two separate applications (with different functionalities) using React Native? Are there features (or libraries) that are meant for this purpose?

By the end of the project, I will have four separate apps: two for Android and two for iOS.

I  have seen some answers to this question, but they mainly seem to apply to a single app having a 'Production', 'Development', and 'Staging' target, with each app being basically the same.

Comment: If they share a lot of the same code, you can just create one app and have the components render differently/route differently based on permissions. I'm building something very similar and its much easier than building two separate apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think what you actually may want here is 3 projects. 1 app for employees and 1 app for managers obviously. But your 3rd project would essentially be a common one for components that will be shared between the 2 apps. Your user class, for example, would go into this project. Then when you are developing your app projects, you can import the common one as a dependency (via `package.json`). This would add your reusable classes to the `node_modules` in your app projects and you can access those by importing them in your app specific classes.

Of course, you could also take Matt's suggestion and build a single app with everything that would just show different routes for employee or managers based on permissions. Just depends on how you want to approach it.

Comment: And how to handle those dependencies that use native code? The linking would be done in both projects 1 and 2, or in the third common project?

Comment: I have the same question. Would love if you or someone else could elaborate this approach to share code across apps the right way.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I followed the old-fashioned way and I had a separate Git repository for each project (2 in total). I also created a third reporitory that contained a library module with all the common code (mainly components but also utils, network-related code, etc). Then, I published this module to npm and added it as a dependency to my 2 projects.

The problem was that this technique was of high maintenance. For example, while working on project 1, I discovered that I wanted to change something in one of my components. This meant that I had to switch projects, update the library, push a new version to npm, switch projects again, update project 1 (and 2) with the new version and continue working until I discovered that there's another change that I need somewhere in the library. And this happened way more often than I initially thought.

Sometime ago I was asked to do something similar again. I read a few articles about best practices and decided to follow the pattern described in [this article](https://medium.com/@patrickleet/mono-repo-or-multi-repo-why-choose-one-when-you-can-have-both-e9c77bd0c668). To summarize it, I now have one single Git repository with multiple modules: one for each feature and one for each app. I use [Lerna](https://lernajs.io/) for managing the modules and although it's still a bit early to say, it feels much better than before.

That said, there's obviously no such thing as a single correct answer but for our project, in our 2-member team, this works fine... so far.

Comment: Hey are you still working in that project? how did it scale after almost a year?